# An MCQ question on continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous bounded function, then :
>
> **A.** $f$ has to be uniform continuous.
>
> **B.** There exists an $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x$
>
> **C.** $f$ cannot be increasing.
>
> **D.** $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists.

**My attempt:**

A counter-example for **(D)** can be $f(x)=\sin(x)$

Also **(C)** is not true. My example is

$f(x)=  \mathbb{e}^x$ when $x\in (-\infty,0]\,\,\,\,\,$ ; and

$f(x)=2-\frac{1}{x+1}$ when $x\in (0,\infty)$

The function is bounded by $0$ and $2$.

Though I'd like you to give me a simpler example. This was the only thing that came to my mind.

Also i have no clue about $A$  and $B$

Though my intuition says, the correct choice is **(B)**.

But you are not really allowed to "guess" in mathematics!!

Comment: for **C**, wouldn't $x\mapsto \arctan x$ do the job?

Comment: @Clement C. : Haha! Yes! I knew there were simpler examples. Thanks. Any comments on A. and B.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $f(x)=\sin x^2$

B Let $M$ be a bound for $f$, i.e. $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x$. Then for the continuous function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ we have $g(-M)>0$ and $g(M)<0$, hence by the IVT $g(x)=0$ (i.e. $f(x)=x$) for some $x\in(-M,M)$.

C $f(x)=\frac x{1+|x|}$

D $f(x)=\sin x$

Comment: I had a feeling about IVT. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

- **C.** $x\mapsto \arctan x$ is increasing, continuous and bounded.
- **B.** By contradiction, assume (wlog) $f$ bounded and continuous such that $f(x) < x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (indeed, $g\colon x \mapsto f(x)-x$ is continuous and never cancels, so it must be either always positive or always negative). Then $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = -\infty$, yielding a contradiction.
- **A.** $x\mapsto \sin x^2$ is [not uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218971/prove-that-the-function-fx-sinx2-is-not-uniformly-continuous-on-the-dom).

Comment: Thank you so much! That is why i love proofs by contradiction. Beautiful. :D