# Determine if $h(x)=\sin(x^2)$ is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity

Normally I know how to do these kind of questions using different kind of methods, but on this specific one I have no idea what to do:

Determine if $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$ is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$

any solutions or maybe advice? Thanks!

Comment: See also: [Prove that the function$f(x)=\sin(x^2)$ is not uniformly continuous on the domain $\mathbb{R}$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218971/prove-that-the-function-fx-sinx2-is-not-uniformly-continuous-on-the-dom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: As $x$ becomes very large, how much of a change in $x$ does it take to complete one period of the sine function? Can you use this to answer the question? As a further hint, suppose $x$ is large and $\delta = c/x$ where $c$ is some positive constant. Then what is $(x + \delta)^2$, compared to $x^2$?

Comment: Their ratio is about $1$ but the difference will be about $2c$. And that is for ANY $c$ and $x$, as $x$ becomes large

Comment: $x$ and $x+\delta$ are as close as you want as $x$ becomes large, but the difference between their squares is about $2c$. Just choose $x^2$ to be an arbitrarily large multiple of $2 \pi$ and $(x+\delta)^2$ to be $\pi/2$ more.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the values at $\sqrt{(2 n + 1/2)\pi}$ and $\sqrt{(2n - 1/2)\pi}$