# If there is a sequence of zeros of a function and this sequence tends to $0$, then is $f$ not periodic, true or false?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, periodic-functions

> If there is a sequence of zeros of a function and this sequence tends to 0, then is $f$ not periodic, true or false?

I think it is false, for example, if we consider the function $\cos(\frac1{\sqrt x})$ for $x>0$, in intervals of amplitude equal to the largest zero of the function, we will obtain a periodic function, but however , the distance between its zeros also converges to $0$.

[image]

**But I would like to know what hypotheses would have to be added to be true, if it is always false or not,...**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you assuming the function is continuous?

Comment: $\cos(\frac1{\sqrt x})$ is not periodic.

Comment: Technically $f(x)=0$ is periodic and $(\frac{1}{n})$ is a sequence of zeros of $f$ that converges to $0$.

Comment: You can start with any continuous function  on $[0, 1]$, having zeros  accumulating at $x=0$, and $f(0) = f(1) = 0$.  Then extend $f$ to a periodic function on $\Bbb R $ by setting $f(x+n) = f(x)$ for all integers $n$.

Comment: You can even have $f \equiv 0$ on $[0,1]$,  $f>0$ on $(1,2)$, $f(2)=0$ and $f$ periodic with period $2$.

Comment: See the drawing (illustrative only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f(x)=\sin(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\right)$ (and define it as $0$ where that is undefined) for a continuous counterexample.

Here's [how it looks](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5klfxak5kz)

Answer (score 6):

The statement is false, as you correctly said. Apart from the “trivial” case that $f$ is identically zero, there are many continuous periodic functions on $\Bbb R$ with zeros accumulating at zero.

Your example does not work however, because $\cos(\frac1{\sqrt x})$ is not periodic.

A simple example (inspired by geetha290krm's comment) is $f(x) = \min(\sin(x), 0)$, which is $2\pi$-periodic and identically zero on $[0, \pi]$.

But you can start with any continuous function on an interval $[0, T]$, having zeros  accumulating at $x=0$, and $f(0) = f(T) = 0$.  Then extend $f$ to a periodic function on $\Bbb R $ by setting $f(x+nT) = f(x)$ for all integers $n$.

Comment: And if instead of having a succession of zeros, we have a function that gives us the difference between two consecutive zeros, and this is decreasing and has a limit of 0, can I conclude that $f$ is not periodic?

Look:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1454070/1049667

Comment: @CPMP: No, you can't. There is already a comment at that answer explaining why the argument is wrong.

Comment: ok, thank you for help